# Image stretching due to AMP

Tags: css, vue.js, amp-html

My images are stretching on this page and I cannot identify why. A fix would be much appreciated.

It seemed to first happen after I added Bootstrap, but I have a customized version of the bootstrap that only includes the grid system and form control stylings, so there shouldn't be a conflict.

https://codepen.io/Mortiferr/pen/MBNqxO

```
.text-centered {
    text-align: center;
}
.sku {
    color: gray;
}
.margin-minus-1 {
    margin-top: -1em;
}
.wrapper-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
.wrapper-link:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
.wrapper-link:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
.product {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.hamburger {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.1em 0 0.2em 0.3em;
    display: inline;
}
.headerbar {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.site-name--container {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.site-name {
    width: 10em;
    margin-top: 0.3em;
    margin-bottom: 0.3em;
}
.sidebar {
    padding: 2em;
    margin: 0;
}
.sidebar > li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sidebar a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.close-sidebar {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-top: 1em;
}
.get-price {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
.get-price-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #D83B34;
    color: white;
    background-color: #D83B34;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
.get-price-link:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #D83B34;
    color: #D83B34;
    background-color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.app-container {
    margin: 1em;
}
```

This is all I have as far as CSS goes, I really am not sure why this is occuring. Is it related to Bootstrap?

Comment: for your image, uses `img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}` instead of `img {max-width:100%;min-width:100%;max-height:100%;min-height:100%}`

Comment: @Sphinx I don't have that CSS that I've added. It must be something AMP is adding. They have pretty strict guidelines, so anything they inject I can't change. It wasn't doing this before, so I did something along the way.

Comment: Can you try putting hardcoded width and height into the <img> and see if it overrides AMP's stuff. Here's a clue that AMP is doing something beyond your code... there's a class 'i-amphtml-replaced-content'.

Comment: the link is not a valid AMP document. that may be part of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your JS that you have the delete tags around that's messing with the images. If you delete it and hard code the image `src` into the `amp-img` tag the images go to the right scale - so long as you replace the 1000x1000 with the 408x287 dimensions of the placeholder image. I'm guessing the Vue and v0.js are clashing.

Also I'm assuming where you have `<!-- delete -->` around all your Vue that you're aware that JS is not allowed in AMP. You can use `amp-list` the same way as you're using for the description info under the images to do the image URL as well if you want to automate the product listing fully.

Because of your Vue and a few other things you're sitting at quite a few errors (I pasted your code into the [AMP Playground](https://ampbyexample.com/playground/)).

[image: Errors in AMP Playground]

Comment: Hey Craig, I appreciate you taking the time to answer. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "You can use amp-list the same way as you're using for the description info under the images to do the image URL as well if you want to automate the product listing fully." Thanks!

Comment: Oh, maybe you aren't using amp-list? I just saw the mustache tags and assumed (d'oh)... Check out the amp-list example (https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-list/). You could build out a JSON file that includes your image url, section titles, etc. and then use mustache tags to fill all that data in. AMP By Example does a pretty good job of explaining but if you need further explanation let me know and I can put together an example.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I will definitely check that out! I was using Vue to generate the HTML, but this looks like it might be far more efficient. I'll tinker with it myself and if I get stuck beyond help I'll give you a shout. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

check if this solution is okay for you.
Add the following code to your CSS.

```
.i-amphtml-layout-size-defined .i-amphtml-fill-content {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

i-amphtml-sizer{
   padding: 0% !important;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use this because of the reasoning I explained above. `I don't have that CSS that I've added. It must be something AMP is adding. They have pretty strict guidelines, so anything they inject I can't change. It wasn't doing this before, so I did something along the way.`